# Umbrella term for classes that all serve another class

Tags: php, oop

I'm looking for an umbrella term for classes which are separated from a main class in order to achieve necessary encapsulation and keep main class reasonably sized.

E.g. each blog post is an instance of *BlogPost* which is in turn served by separate classes for:

- creations and updates,
- getting and saving tags,
- getting associated URLs,
- caching and indexing
- etc.

They all:

- Are never instantiated outside of *BlogPost*.
- Do **not** inherit from *BlogPost*.
- Inherit a few common methods from another intermediate class instead.
- Are mostly different otherwise.

How should these be named?

Comment: Service objects, value/data objects, factories, query objects, policy objects, decorators, view objects, form objects... all related but have specific niche uses.  Many of these are/have well established design patterns

Answer (score 0):

**You can name these classes as helpers and libraries.**

Normally when a data is processed and returned back, we would want to call those classes Helpers while the classes that processes data, i would prefer to call those libraries.

So, here we would have Creation and Updation library:

**Creation:**
You build a class which access 4 parameters say (*creating a simple example here*):

- Blog Name
- Blog Text
- Author
- Created Date & Time

This is passed to the creation library which has the code logic for validation, caching, etc.

**Updation:**
You will have to build a class which accesses 5 parameters (*again creating a simple example here*)

- Blog Id
- Blog Name (*if editable*)
- Updated Blog Text
- Updated Date & Time

While updating the Blog, you might want to check if the same author who has created the Blog is updating it or an admin is editing the blog, updating the caching system, etc

**Tagging:**
This tag might be helpful in

- generating a tag cloud
- Probably handling a search function over tags
- and much more

**Caching & Indexing:**

Caching and Indexing may be handled as two way classes wherein it may act as helper and a library handling Input/Output caching for the blogs and overriding the caching system based on dynamic caching, etc

In this way, these classes will not extend or implement a parent Blog Post Class however, would facilitate to manage the Blog Post logic in a structured and the OOPs way

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Minion is the word you are looking for  :-)

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minion